# pip can't install packages listed in install_requires

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I created a Python package, uploaded it to TestPyPI, and try to install it to a new virtual environment. pip cannot install the required packages, but if I try to install the same packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it works.

I created my `setup.py` file following the guidelines listed in [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/). I uploaded my package to TestPyPI and try to install it to a brand new virtual environment with `Python 3.6.4` and `pip 19.1.1`.

Here is my install instruction: `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ my-package-name==0.0.1`

Here is what I have in `setuptools.setup` call (only related stuff):

```
   packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
    ],
    install_requires=[
        "requests",
        "jsonpickle",
        "pandas",
        "matplotlib",
        "seaborn",
        "Pillow"
    ]
```

It starts by successfull installing matplotlib, but I get the following error later:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jsonpickle (from my-package-name==0.0.1) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jsonpickle (from my-package-name==0.0.1)`

I also tried with specifying package versions, but then I cannot install any packages.

**As I have told, I can install the packages just fine by using `pip install -r requirements.txt` command.**

Comment: This is why you need to understand what the arguments in a command do, not just be able to repeat it blindly. You told it where to look for packages: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#index-url Does the location you gave it have jsonpickle? No, it does not. Using a requirements file would also fail if you included the same option.

Comment: Thanks, I should have searched more for it.

Answer (score 6):

This is an unfortunate (and known) downside to TestPyPI: The issue is that `jsonpickle` does not exist on TestPyPI, and by installing your package from there, you are telling `pip` to look for dependencies there as well.

Instead, you should publish to PyPI instead, and use a pre-release version so as not to pollute your versions. You can delete these pre-releases from the project later.

Answer (score -1):

it's better if you create a requirements.txt file and add the the package you require in that file and in setup.py open that file get the package in list and add that in setup.py

eg

requirements.txt

```
requests
jsonpickle
pandas
matplotlib
seaborn
Pillow
```

and in setup.py

```
with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()

...

setup(
    name='package name',
    version='version',
    install_requires=requirements,
    ...
)
```

why this way ? -> By this way, you only have to maintain requirements.txt and no duplication of same in setup.py

Comment: I get the point but it is not related to my problem. Even if I do it this way, pip still cannot install the required packages.

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for Pillow==6.1.0 (from my-package-name==0.0.1)`

Comment: @goktugerce as mentioned by jpmc26, you are testing it in `test.pypi ` which does n't have these  package , so this is why u are getting error,instead of that do `pip install setup.py` it will work

Comment: `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` are two different things, you shouldn't do this. See https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/

Comment: @DustinIngram here `install_require=requirements` requirements is a list of all the package which needed for project, if this is not wriiten in `requirements.txt` and define in setup.py itself, it is then still a list of package with version, i dont see hwo this shouldn't do

Comment: I'm specifically talking about defining the dependencies in a file called `requirements.txt` and then reading it in to produce `install_requires`, which is what your answer recommends. It also fails to resolve the question as the author has already mentioned.